# Fast-track for marking own question as duplicate?

Tags: feature-request

[Alternative resource folders in Android Studio gets collapsed into one virtual folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35441351)

I posted this question. Dhawal found another question that basically asked the same thing, so I tried to close my question as a duplicate.

I had to suggest a close, wait for other people to review the close reason (my vote seems to have counted in this vote), and then I got the standard "this question has been marked as duplicate".

It seems like this is a good place to allow a fast-track. Marking your own question as a duplicate, if you have "enough" reputation, could skip the review queue.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

If you vote to close your own question a duplicate, you can insta-close it as duplicate by clicking the *Yes, That solved my problem* banner after you voted to close.

It would be best indeed that if you flag/vote to close it, it skips that step and immediately closes it. If you yourself flag/vote, you never actually want other users to confirm that. It doesn't harm the site in any way either since you already have the power to close it yourself.

So that would be a *yes* for this feature request.

Answer (score 1):

Your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35441351/alternative-resource-folders-in-android-studio-gets-collapsed-into-one-virtual-f#comment58604532_35441351):

> And I even have to click the "Yes, That solved my problem" button, and I get the option to edit my question and everything. Haha!

*is* how your close your own question as a duplicate.

You flag your own question as a duplicate, and you get a box asking you whether you want to close your question. If you press the "Yes, that solved my problem" button (as you did), the question gets closed, if you press the other button, it'll ask you to edit the question to clarify it.

[image]

The 'Community' user there means you, the OP, wanted to close the question.

Comment: But that extra step is not necessary, right?

Comment: @PatrickHofman which step?

Comment: To click the banner if you voted to close yourself already.

Comment: @PatrickHofman whoops, forgot you could actually *vote* for your own question; I'm not sure in that case...